# How does Doctrine call a function that does not exist?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, arcasolutions-edirectory

I'm trying to find out why a field is not saving. It's submitted fine and the page reloads with the same value, but it's not stored in the database. I have this in my project

```
            $contact = new Contact($_POST);
            $contact->Save();
```

However, the `Save()` function doesn't exist in the Contact class, and it doesn't extend anything! How is it able to call a function that doesn't exist? I don't believe PHP has monkeypatching. I know the function is called because I added `print_r($_POST)` right above it.

```
<?php

namespace ArcaSolutions\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Contact")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ArcaSolutions\CoreBundle\Repository\ContactRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Contact
{
```

My new field is defined as

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="timezone", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $timezone;

/**
 * Set timezone
 *
 * @param string $timezone
 * @return Contact
 */
public function setTimezone($timezone)
{
    $this->timezone = $timezone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get timezone
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTimezone()
{
    return $this->timezone;
}
```

It's an eDirectory project based on Symfony 2.8 and PHP 5.6.27.

Comment: This is definitely not standard in Symfony / Doctrine. I don't think its even possible. Where did you get this?

Comment: Doctrine 1 used an active record pattern with a save method, is it possible you are mixing versions?

Answer (score 0):

As Padam87 suggests in the comments, you seem to mix Doctrine 1 with Doctrine 2 syntax. Doctrine 1 uses the Active Record pattern, whereas Doctrine 2 uses the Data Mapper pattern. A nice explaination of the differences can be found here: https://www.culttt.com/2014/06/18/whats-difference-active-record-data-mapper/

A Doctrine 2 entity will **never** have a `save()` or similar method. To persist or retrieve entities, you will have to use the entity manager. If you use Symfony, the entity manager can be injected as a service into your controllers or other services.

Read the Doctrine docs on [how to work with an entity manager](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html) to learn more.

By the way, whatever you’re trying by injecting the `$_POST` data into your entity – this is a very bad idea. You should first process this data in your controller or some validator and only fill entities with validated content. Also, when using Symfony, you’ll want to get the POST data through the `Request` object which is passed to your action if you reference it in the signature.

Here’s a stub for a controller which gets the entity manager injected as a dependency (you should also register it the controller as a service in your bundle’s `services.yml`) and gets the POST data from the `Request` object:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();

    // validate $data!!!

    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->setSomeValue($data["value"]);

    $this->entityManager->persist($contact);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return new Response("Ok", 200);
}
```

In Symfony, again, you could also inject an instance of `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface` and [use Symfony’s validation component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html).

Comment: Sorry that's how it's written. eDirectory doesn't use controllers.

Comment: What is eDirectory? From googling, it seems that its some sort of proprietary directory application. But is there any source code or dev docs?

Comment: eDirectory is directory listing software. Yes it's proprietary. https://www.edirectory.com/. The client purchased the source license but there is no developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. There were two Contact classes and eDirectory was using the one in `edirectory\web\classes\class_Contact.php`. The other one I found was in `edirectory\src\ArcaSolutions\CoreBundle\Entity\Contact.php`. The one it really uses is defined as

```
class Contact extends Handle {
    var $account_id;
...
    function Save() {
        $this->prepareToSave();
        $dbObj = db_getDBObject(DEFAULT_DB,true);;
        $sql  = "UPDATE Contact SET"
            . " updated = NOW(),"
            . " first_name = $this->first_name,"
...
```

So it does have a `Save()` function.

Comment: Really, they’re using Doctrine 2 and have implemented a `Save` method on the entity? And they’re doing raw SQL? Inside the entity object? Without prepared statements? (Also, apparently using the contents of the `$_POST` array without prior filtering?) This is f***ed up on so many levels.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's kind of messy. I don't know why they have duplicate entity classes.